# jquery .focus/.blur issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is a spinet of the code I've been working on; the issue is, no matter what I do, I cannot get jQuery to load on the page...or my code is just plain wrong. As far as I can tell everything is in order, does anyone else see anything wrong with my code

Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">      </script>
<script type ="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.text').focus(function() {
 if (this.value == this.title) {
    $(this).val("");
}
}).blur(function() {
if (this.value == "") {
    $(this).val(this.title);
}
});​
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form  action = "backend.php" method = "post">
        <br />
<label for="name">First Name</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "fName" class = "text" value ="first" title="first"  /><br />

<label for ="realm"> Last name</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "lName" /><br />
    <button type="submit" value = "submit">submit</button>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to close the `<script>` element with a `</script>`

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me, but you forgot the class on the second input if you intended it to work on both? -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uZ26K/2/)

Comment: You have a hidden character after the second last line in your inline code (`});`). Delete the full line and type it again, and it should work.

Comment: Cleaned it up a bit -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uZ26K/4/)